# d3.js adding a triangles on lines in force-directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes

I have force directed graph id d3.js which I'm using just for fun. Currently it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/WNSTf/

I wanna add little triangles on those two black lines, so they would look like arrows. I've tried to add triangle with path, but I don't know how to append it to lines..

script:

```
var data = {"nodes":[
        {"name":"Action 4", "type":5, "slug": "", "value":265000},
        {"name":"Action 5", "type":6, "slug": "", "value":23000},
        {"name":"Action 3", "type":4, "slug": "", "value":115000},
        {"name":"Iron Man", "type":1, "slug": "Iron_Man",
            "img_href": "http://www.1sticondesign.com/core/free/Ironman-128.png"},
        {"name":"Superman", "type":1, "slug": "Superman",
            "img_href":"http://www.desktop-icon.com/stock-icons/desktop-boss/superman-icon.gif"},
        {"name":"Action 1", "type":2, "slug": "",},
        {"name":"Action 2", "type":3, "slug": "",},
        {"name":"Batman", "type":1, "slug": "Batman", "img_href": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshock/batman/256/Batman-icon.png"}
                    ], 
            "links":[
        {"source":0,"target":3,"value":10},
        {"source":4,"target":3,"value":1},
        {"source":1,"target":7,"value":10},
        {"source":2,"target":4,"value":10},
        {"source":4,"target":7,"value":1},
        {"source":4,"target":5,"value":10},
        {"source":4,"target":6,"value":10}
                    ]
   }     

var w = 560,
    h = 500,
radius = d3.scale.log()
    .domain([0, 312000])
    .range(["10", "50"]);

var vis = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

//d3.json(data, function(json) {
    var force = self.force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(data.nodes)
        .links(data.links)
        .distance(100)
        .charge(-1000)
        .size([w, h])
        .start();

    var link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
        .data(data.links)
        .enter().append("svg:line")
        .attr("class", function (d) { return "link" + d.value +""; })
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });


    function openLink() {
    return function(d) {
        var url = "";
        if(d.type == 1) {
            url = "wiki/" + d.slug
        } //else if(d.type == 2) {
            //url = "clients/" + d.slug
        //} else if(d.type == 3) {
            //url = "agencies/" + d.slug
        //}
        window.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/"+url)
    }
}


    var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(data.nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .call(force.drag);

    node.append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d){ return "node type"+d.type})
        .attr("r", function(d) { return radius(d.value) || 10 })
      //.style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.type); })
      .call(force.drag);

    node.append("svg:image")
        .attr("class", "circle")
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return d.img_href})
        .attr("x", "-16px")
        .attr("y", "-16px")
        .attr("width", "32px")
        .attr("height", "32px")
        .on("click", openLink());

    node.append("svg:text")
        .attr("class", "nodetext")
        .attr("dx", 16)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name });

    force.on("tick", function() {
      link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

      node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    });
//});
```

css:

```
.link10 { stroke: #ccc; stroke-width: 3px; stroke-dasharray: 3, 3; }
.link1 { stroke: #000; stroke-width: 3px;}
.nodetext { pointer-events: none; font: 10px sans-serif; }

.node.type1 {
  fill:brown;
}
.node.type2 {
  fill:#337147;
}
.node.type3 {
  fill:blue;
}
.node.type4 {
  fill:red;
}

.node.type5 {
    fill:#1BC9E0;
}

.node.type6 {
    fill:#E01B98;
}

image.circle {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Could you possibly show me in my jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you split up the data entry block and define a variable for

```
var links = svg.selectAll('line.link')
    .data(data.link)
    .enter()
```

You can append multiple different things the selection you have defined as `links`. You aren't adding more elements to the lines, per se, but rather adding elements to the selections that you are adding the lines to, corresponding to adding shapes to lines in a one to one ratio.

I've modified [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WNSTf/1/) to add a circle to the middle of each line.

If you want to only add elements to the black lines, you can use a filter to do so by creating a new data set and operating on that.

Comment: I've made up myself with markers, but I love your answer to this, and will use it for sure, thanks! :)